# Does a Citizen of Antigua and Barbuda need to apply for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, europe, schengen-visas

Do I still need to apply for a UK visa while Antigua and Barbuda is under  “countries whose citizens are not required to obtain a Schengen visa in order to enter any member country of the Schengen Area for tourism or business purposes”.

I’m hearing that if I obtain the British Visa I will more likely enter the country while a Schengen visa doesn’t automatically let you enter in, and I will be able to travel across Europe as well.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa is the standard place to look, and it seems to say that you don't need a visa (may depend on the reason for your travel, though).  Schengen visa policies are irrelevant as they have never applied to the UK.

Comment: Note that at this time, due to the ongoing Covid-19 crisis, people who are not citizens or permanent residents of the EU or UK or immediate family members are not allowed in the EU or the UK.

Comment: @jcaron I don't think the UK has implemented a ban on entry yet?

Comment: @BritishSam I was under the impression that the EU ban, since it allows UK citizens/residents in, also applied to the UK borders, but I have to admit that may have been a shortcut I took too quickly.

Comment: @jcaron does the EU ban even apply to Ireland?  Normally such statements apply only to Schengen countries (and perhaps the candidate countries Romania, Bulgaria, Croatia and Cyprus).

Comment: @phoog I'm really not that sure. Communication on this ban has been even more vague than Mr. Trump's I'm afraid.

Comment: @jcaron think its a Schengen ban, but EU citizens still allowed in and the EU is treating UK citizens as EU citizens during the transition period